# How to remove paragraph tag <p> with contains special word in preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, paragraph

For example i have this following code :

```
$string = '<p>i need to go to my room</p><p>i don't need to go to school</p><p>i need to study everywhere</p>';
```

Now, I want to remove the paragraph that contain words 'to school'. 
The output I want is `<p>`i need to go to my room `</p><p>`i need to study everywhere `</p>`

How do i do it with preg_replace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is generally **evil** and bad practice to use regex to parse HTML.  But, assuming you only have a string with a set of top level HTML `<p>` tags, regex might be an option here.

```
$string = "<p>i need to go to my room</p><p>i don't need to go to school</p><p>i need to study everywhere</p>";
$output = preg_replace("/<p>((?!<\/p>).)*\bto school\b.*?<\/p>/", "2000", $string);
echo $output;
```

This outputs:

```
<p>i need to go to my room</p>2000<p>i need to study everywhere</p>
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
<p>            match an initial <p> tag
((?!<\/p>).)*  match any character, provided that we do not
               encounter a closing </p> tag

\bto school\b  match the literal text "to school"
.*?<\/p>       consume the remainder until the first closing </p>
```

The only perhaps tricky part of the above regex is:

```
((?!<\/p>).)*
```

This is a *tempered* dot, and it works by applying a negative lookahead `(?!</p>)` at each step we match any character.  This is critical, because it ensures that the regex engine will not accidentally cross over multiple `<p>` tags to find `to school`.

Comment: it's work.. to get what i want i just change '2000' to empty.. thank u very much..

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace ( "<p[^<]*to school[^<]*<\/p>" , "" , $string);
echo $result;
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Tj0Jdx/1)

---

Note: I do not have PHP at hand to test, but the regex should work, as tested on Regex101.

Comment: What do you mean "blank result"?

Comment: I added an "echo" and now it should be OK. Or?

Comment: still blank result.. but ii tried to add / before <p and after /p>.. now it's work.. many thanks..